# Cannot get int to be displayed in text box for dice roller app

Tags: c#, dice

I'm trying to get back into programming and I'm having trouble getting the final int answers into the text boxes at the end. It has been a few years since I've coded, so if I messed up big time, please let me know.

````
     {
         int dice_total;
         int dice_num;
         int diff_num;
         int succ_num = 0;
         int ones = 0;
         Boolean comp_num = false;
         string Succ;
         string Comp;

         dice_total = int.Parse(Dice.Text);
         diff_num = int.Parse(Diff.Text);
         Random random = new Random();
         dice_num = random.Next(dice_total);
         
         if (dice_num >= diff_num)
         {
             succ_num++;
         }
         else
         {
             if (dice_num == 1)
             {
                 ones++;
             }
         }

         if (ones >= succ_num)
         {
             comp_num = true;
         }
         else
         {
             comp_num = false;
         }

         Succ = succ_num.ToString();
        
         Comp = comp_num.ToString();
         
         
     }```
````

Comment: I don't see any attempt to set the text of a text box. Assuming this is WinForms, it is just `[your text box name].Text = [some string];`

Comment: I realized what I did wrong. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[your text box name].Text=[some int].ToString();
```

For example:

```
label1.Text = product.BuyingPrice.ToString();
```

Comment: Whenever I try. it gives me an error with the .Text (Error CS1061)

Comment: You can explain it more?

Comment: Because I still had string at the top section, it wasn't liking the double. Now I am just trying to remember how to do a loop.

Comment: for (int i = 0; i<    [   Stop conditions  ]; i++)
{
[The code that is supposed to repeat itself]
}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I can't seem to get it count up the successes. For those who don't know, WoD has you roll d10s and you are given a difficulty. You have to roll that difficulty number or higher to get successes. If there are more (or equal) 1s than total successes, its a complication. This isn't even including code for when you roll a 10 (which has you roll again while still counting as a success).

Ex. Roll 5d10s with a difficulty of 6
6, 8, 10, 1, 1 = 3 success
Roll again for the 10: 1
Total: 3 successes and a complication

```
using Accord.Math.Distances;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Roller
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        int dice_total;
        int dice_add;
        int dice_num;
        int diff_num;
        int succ_num = 0;
        int ones = 0;
        Boolean comp_num = false;


        public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
 

            dice_total = int.Parse(Dice.Text);
            diff_num = int.Parse(Diff.Text);
            

            for (dice_add = 0; dice_add < dice_total; dice_add++)
            {
                Random random = new Random();
                dice_num = random.Next(dice_total);

                if (dice_num >= diff_num)
                {
                    succ_num++;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (dice_num == 1)
                    {
                        ones++;
                    }
                }

                if (ones >= succ_num)
                {
                    comp_num = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    comp_num = false;
                }

            }
            Succ.Text = succ_num.ToString();
            Comp.Text = comp_num.ToString();

        }


    }
}
```

Comment: This is not an answer. And it seems like your first question has been answered. Please only make one question per post. This seems to be a new question on its own.